# Using Ajax to fetch data from database - Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I am using ajax to retrieve data from my database into a select box. When i select a group, it should displays it contents respectively.

When i try to display the form, it says `Undefined variable: packages` but i have return package in the view in my controller.

Is there anything i am missing out ?

**PackageController**

```
 public function create()
    {
        $groups = Group::all();
       $selectedGroup = $group->pluck('id')->toArray();
        return view('group.detail',compact('selectedGroup','groups'));
    }


    public function getpackages($id)
   {
    $groups =  Group::findOrFail($id);
    $packages= $groups->packages;

    return view('group.detail',compact('packages'));
    return $id;

   }
```

**group.details.blade.php**

```
<div class="input-group control-group after-add-more">

          <div class="form-group">
          <!-- <label for="select" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Select Item</label> -->
          <div class="col-lg-10">
          <select class="form-control" id="group" name="group[]" mulitple>
          @foreach($groups as $group)
          <option value="{!! $group->id !!}" @if(in_array($group->id, $selectedGroup)) selected="selected" @endif >
                         {!! $group->name!!}
          </option>
              @endforeach
          </select>


          </div>


          </div>


          <div class="form-group">
          <!-- <label for="select" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Select Item</label> -->
          <div class="col-lg-10">
          <select class="form-control" id="remove_select" name="packages" mulitple>
          @foreach($packages as $package)
          <option value="{!! $package->id !!}" >
                         {!! $package->name!!}
          </option>
              @endforeach
          </select>



          </div>


          </div>


<script>
 $('#category').change(function(e)
 {
 e.preventDefault();

$y = $(this).val();
  alert($y);

$.ajax
 ({
 url: '{{ url('getpackages') }}/'+$y,
 type: 'GET',
 dataType: 'json',
 success: function(data)
 {
 console.log(data);
 }
 });
 });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Both of your controller actions are using the same view, but neither of them are passing in all of the values that the view expects. When the `create` controller action loads the view, it does not define the `$packages` variable, which is why you are getting that notice.

You need to break your view into two separate views: One for the `create` controller action and one for the `getpackages` controller action.

I think the underlying issue here is that you are not treating your initial request and your ajax request separately.

Comment: Break view into two seperate views? How is that done as i am new to this

Comment: @LearnProgramming You need two separate blade templates, not one.

Comment: Then i would have to find a different way because i can't have separate views with what i want to achieve

Comment: @LearnProgramming There is definitely a higher level issue here that I don't have enough context to address. The immediate issue is that you are trying to combine two separate views into one blade template. That will not work. Your initial request and your ajax request are two entirely separate things and need to be treated as such.

Comment: I actually want them in the same controller. So when i select a group, it's content is displayed in another select box below

Comment: @LearnProgramming It's fine to group separate but related actions in a controller. It is not fine to attempt to group separate but related views into a single blade template.